# clang-format: always force arguments and parameters to one-line-each

Tags: clang-format

Is there any way to always force arguments and parameters to one-line-each?

For example, this:

```
if(value != "course" || value != "module" || value != "lesson")
```

Should look like this:

```
if(value != "course" ||
   value != "module" ||
   value != "lesson")
```

Or this:

```
if(value != "course"
|| value != "module"
|| value != "lesson")
```

And this:

```
void some_class::some_func(const std:string s, const std::string t)
```

Should look like this:

```
void some_class::some_func(const std:string s,
                           const std::string t)
```

Or this:

```
void some_class::some_func(const std:string s
                           , const std::string t)
```

[My .clang-format.](http://pastebin.com/KAB4srNT)

Comment: You have reposted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626/clang-format-force-binpackarguments-and-binpackparameters-to-one-line-each-if-t) instead of editing this question. So, please delete this yourself.

Comment: No, they are different questions. I originally had them in one post and someone came in and complained about it so I put both questions in different posts.

Comment: Is the difference the word "only", I don't see another difference.

Comment: The difference is that in one case, I want parameters to ALWAYS go one per line like above, and in the other case I want then to go one per line ONLY IF they overflow (text goes past the ColumnLimit.)