# clang-format: force arguments and parameters to one-line-each if the statement overflows

Tags: clang-format

Is there a way to force arguments and parameters to one-line-each if a single or more character go past the overflow?

For example:

For example, this:

```
if(value != "course" || value != "module" || value != "lesson"
)
```

Should look like this:

```
if(value != "course" ||
   value != "module" ||
   value != "lesson")
```

Or this:

```
if(value != "course"
|| value != "module"
|| value != "lesson")
```

And this:

```
void some_class::some_func(const std:string s, const std::string t
)
```

Should look like this:

```
void some_class::some_func(const std:string s,
                           const std::string t)
```

Or this:

```
void some_class::some_func(const std:string s
                           , const std::string t)
```

Edit:

[My .clang-format](http://pastebin.com/KAB4srNT):

```
#http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

# The style used for all options not specifically set in the configuration.
# This option is supported only in the clang-format configuration (both within -style='{...}' and the .clang-format file).
# LLVM A style complying with the LLVM coding standards
# Google A style complying with Google’s C++ style guide
# Chromium A style complying with Chromium’s style guide
# Mozilla A style complying with Mozilla’s style guide
# WebKit A style complying with WebKit’s style guide
#BasedOnStyle: Webkit

# The extra indent or outdent of access modifiers, e.g. public:.
AccessModifierOffset: -4

# If true, horizontally aligns arguments after an open bracket.
# This applies to round brackets (parentheses), angle brackets and square brackets. This will result in formattings like code someLongFunction(argument1, argument2); endcode
#AlignAfterOpenBracket: false

# If true, aligns escaped newlines as far left as possible. Otherwise puts them into the right-most column.
#AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft

# If true, horizontally align operands of binary and ternary expressions.
AlignOperands: true

# If true, aligns trailing comments.
AlignTrailingComments: true

# Allow putting all parameters of a function declaration onto the next line even if BinPackParameters is false.
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false

# Allows contracting simple braced statements to a single line.
# E.g., this allows if (a) { return; } to be put on a single line.
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true

# If true, short case labels will be contracted to a single line.
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true

# Dependent on the value, int f() { return 0; } can be put on a single line.
# SFS_None (in configuration: None) Never merge functions into a single line.
# SFS_Inline (in configuration: Inline) Only merge functions defined inside a class.
# SFS_Empty (in configuration: Empty) Only merge empty functions.
# SFS_All (in configuration: All) Merge all functions fitting on a single line.
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline

# If true, if (a) return; can be put on a single line.
#AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false

# If true, while (true) continue; can be put on a single line.
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true

# If true, always break after function definition return types.
# More truthfully called ‘break before the identifier following the type in a function definition’. PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine becomes irrelevant.
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: false

# If true, always break before multiline string literals.
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false

# If true, always break after the template<...> of a template declaration.
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true

# If false, a function call’s arguments will either be all on the same line or will have one line each.
BinPackArguments: true

# If false, a function call’s arguments will either be all
# on the same line or will have one line each.
BinPackParameters: true

# The way to wrap binary operators.
# BOS_None (in configuration: None) Break after operators.
# BOS_NonAssignment (in configuration: NonAssignment) Break before operators that aren’t assignments.
# BOS_All (in configuration: All) Break before operators.
#BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None

# The brace breaking style to use.
# BS_Attach (in configuration: Attach) Always attach braces to surrounding context.
# BS_Linux (in configuration: Linux) Like Attach, but break before braces on function, namespace and class definitions.
# BS_Stroustrup (in configuration: Stroustrup) Like Attach, but break before function definitions, and ‘else’.
# BS_Allman (in configuration: Allman) Always break before braces.
# BS_GNU (in configuration: GNU) Always break before braces and add an extra level of indentation to braces of control statements, not to those of class, function or other definitions.
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman

# If true, ternary operators will be placed after line breaks.
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true

# Always break constructor initializers before commas and align the commas with the colon.
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true

# Always break constructor initializers before commas and align the commas with the colon.
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true

# The column limit.
# A column limit of 0 means that there is no column limit. In this case, clang-format will respect the input’s line breaking decisions within statements unless they contradict other rules.
ColumnLimit: 80

# A regular expression that describes comments with special meaning, which should not be split into lines or otherwise changed.
CommentPragmas: "\/*(.*)*\/"

# If the constructor initializers don’t fit on a line, put each initializer on its own line.
#ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false

# The number of characters to use for indentation of constructor initializer lists.
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0

# Indent width for line continuations.
#ContinuationIndentWidth: 4

# If true, format braced lists as best suited for C++11 braced lists.
# Important differences: - No spaces inside the braced list. - No line break before the closing brace. - Indentation with the continuation indent, not with the block indent.
# Fundamentally, C++11 braced lists are formatted exactly like function calls would be formatted in their place. If the braced list follows a name (e.g. a type or variable name), clang-format formats as if the {} were the parentheses of a function call with that name. If there is no name, a zero-length name is assumed.
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true

# If true, analyze the formatted file for the most common alignment of & and *. Point
#DerivePointerAlignment: false

# Disables formatting at all.
#DisableFormat: false

# If true, clang-format detects whether function calls and definitions are formatted with one parameter per line.
# Each call can be bin-packed, one-per-line or inconclusive. If it is inconclusive, e.g. completely on one line, but a decision needs to be made, clang-format analyzes whether there are other bin-packed cases in the input file and act accordingly.
# NOTE: This is an experimental flag, that might go away or be renamed. Do not use this in config files, etc. Use at your own risk.
#ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false

# A vector of macros that should be interpreted as foreach loops instead of as function calls.
# These are expected to be macros of the form: code FOREACH(<variable-declaration>, ...) <loop-body> endcode
# For example: BOOST_FOREACH.
#ForEachMacros (std::vector<std::string>)

# Indent case labels one level from the switch statement.
# When false, use the same indentation level as for the switch statement. Switch statement body is always indented one level more than case labels.
IndentCaseLabels: false

# The number of columns to use for indentation.
IndentWidth: 4

# Indent if a function definition or declaration is wrapped after the type.
#IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false

# If true, empty lines at the start of blocks are kept.
#KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false

# Language, this format style is targeted at.
# LK_None (in configuration: None) Do not use.
# LK_Cpp (in configuration: Cpp) Should be used for C, C++, ObjectiveC, ObjectiveC++.
# LK_Java (in configuration: Java) Should be used for Java.
# LK_JavaScript (in configuration: JavaScript) Should be used for JavaScript.
# LK_Proto (in configuration: Proto) Should be used for Protocol Buffers (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).
Language: Cpp

# The maximum number of consecutive empty lines to keep.
#MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 0

# The indentation used for namespaces.
# NI_None (in configuration: None) Don’t indent in namespaces.
# NI_Inner (in configuration: Inner) Indent only in inner namespaces (nested in other namespaces).
# NI_All (in configuration: All) Indent in all namespaces.
#NamespaceIndentation: Inner

# The number of characters to use for indentation of ObjC blocks.
#ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4

# Add a space after @property in Objective-C, i.e. use \@property (readonly) instead of \@property(readonly).
#ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false

# Add a space in front of an Objective-C protocol list, i.e. use Foo <Protocol> instead of Foo<Protocol>.
#ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false

# The penalty for breaking a function call after “call(”.
#PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter (unsigned)

# The penalty for each line break introduced inside a comment.
#PenaltyBreakComment (unsigned)

# The penalty for breaking before the first <<.
#PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess (unsigned)

# The penalty for each line break introduced inside a string literal.
#PenaltyBreakString (unsigned)

# The penalty for each character outside of the column limit.
#PenaltyExcessCharacter (unsigned)

# Penalty for putting the return type of a function onto its own line.
#PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine (unsigned)

# If true, analyze the formatted file for the most common alignment of & and *. PointerAlignment is then used only as fallback.
PointerAlignment: Middle

# If true, a space may be inserted after C style casts.
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false

# If false, spaces will be removed before assignment operators.
#SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true

# Defines in which cases to put a space before opening parentheses.
# SBPO_Never (in configuration: Never) Never put a space before opening parentheses.
# SBPO_ControlStatements (in configuration: ControlStatements) Put a space before opening parentheses only after control statement keywords (for/if/while...).
# SBPO_Always (in configuration: Always) Always put a space before opening parentheses, except when it’s prohibited by the syntax rules (in function-like macro definitions) or when determined by other style rules (after unary operators, opening parentheses, etc.)
SpaceBeforeParens: Never

# If true, spaces may be inserted into ‘()’.
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false

# The number of spaces before trailing line comments (// - comments).
# This does not affect trailing block comments (/**/ - comments) as those commonly have different usage patterns and a number of special cases.
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1

# If true, spaces will be inserted after ‘<’ and before ‘>’ in template argument lists
SpacesInAngles: false

# If true, spaces may be inserted into C style casts.
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false

# If true, spaces are inserted inside container literals (e.g. ObjC and Javascript array and dict literals).
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false

# If true, spaces will be inserted after ‘(‘ and before ‘)’.
SpacesInParentheses: false

# If true, spaces will be inserted after ‘[‘ and before ‘]’.
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false

# Format compatible with this standard, e.g. use A<A<int> > instead of A<A<int>> for LS_Cpp03.
# LS_Cpp03 (in configuration: Cpp03) Use C++03-compatible syntax.
# LS_Cpp11 (in configuration: Cpp11) Use features of C++11 (e.g. A<A<int>> instead of A<A<int> >).
# LS_Auto (in configuration: Auto) Automatic detection based on the input.
Standard: Cpp11

# The number of columns used for tab stops.
#TabWidth: 4

# The way to use tab characters in the resulting file.
# UT_Never (in configuration: Never) Never use tab.
# UT_ForIndentation (in configuration: ForIndentation) Use tabs only for indentation.
# UT_Always (in configuration: Always) Use tabs whenever we need to fill whitespace that spans at least from one tab stop to the next one.
UseTab: Never
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Set:

```
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
```

And make sure

```
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```

Or not defined.

Comment: Add 'AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine = false' to makesure function call one argument on one line.

Comment: This doesn't work when the parameter length doesn't execeed the `ColumnLimit`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment out the following option

`#BreakBeforeBinaryOperators:`