# clang-format: how to prevent all function arguments on next line?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have a C++ function call that I've manually and intentionally formatted like
this:

```
DoSomethingForAPurposeThatCausesALongFunctionName(
    arg_0,
    arg_1,
    arg_2);
```

clang-format wants to re-format it like this:

```
DoSomethingForAPurposeThatCausesALongFunctionName(
    arg_0, arg_1, arg_2)
```

I do not want this. `AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine` appears to
control this behavior for function declarations, but what about function calls?
Is there a corresponding setting?

My `.clang-format` looks like this:

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clang-format: force arguments and parameters to one-line-each if the statement overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626/clang-format-force-arguments-and-parameters-to-one-line-each-if-the-statement-o)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in preventing multiple arguments on the same line, but below the `fun(` line. In my case, I don't mind if the first argument is still on the same line as `fun(`. I just want them to either be all on the `fun(` line or all stacked.

I was able to achieve this by increasing `PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter` to 100.
Presumably you may need a different value depending on your other penalty settings.

This yields:

```
fun(my_long_argument_0,
    my_long_argument_1,
    my_long_argument_2);
```

In your case, assuming `DoSomethingForAPurposeThatCausesALongFunctionName(arg_0,` is too long for one line, it would yield:

```
DoSomethingForAPurposeThatCausesALongFunctionName(
    arg_0,
    arg_1,
    arg_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration is correct to get your desired formatting with clang-format 5.0.

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
BinPackParameters: false
```

Comment: Same problem. Already have the suggested settings and `clang-format` keep all arguments on single line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the top voted answer from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626/clang-format-force-arguments-and-parameters-to-one-line-each-if-the-statement-o)
 worked for me,

try setting:

```
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
```

And make sure

```
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```

or not defined.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need

```
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
```

It works for me unless the first argument is on the same line as the function call, in which case it puts them all on the same line.

I also have

```
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
```

which may have some effect?

I'm using version 3.8.0.

Comment: This is incorrect, setting that parameter has no effect on the behavior in question.

Comment: You're right - it seemed like it was having an effect, but it does the same thing regardless. I find that it keeps them all on separate lines unless the first one is on the same line as the opening bracket.