# clang-format force each argument / parameter to own line when column exceeded?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am trying to figure out if it is possible with clang-format for get the arguments / parameters the way I am looking.

I have tried a number of things however so far I can only get this:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,153 + floor(toGreenRed * percentage),51 + floor(toGreenGreen * percentage),51 + floor(toGreenBlue * percentage),255);
```

to format into this:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,
  153 + floor(toGreenRed * percentage),
  51 + floor(toGreenGreen * percentage),
  51 + floor(toGreenBlue * percentage),
  255);
```

but I want this:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(
  renderer,
  153 + floor(toGreenRed * percentage),
  51 + floor(toGreenGreen * percentage),
  51 + floor(toGreenBlue * percentage),
  255
);
```

also currently this:

```
void renderHealthBox( SDL_Renderer *renderer, int sideUiWidth, int yOffset, float percentage, float laksjdlkajsdlkasjdlkasjd) {
```

formats into this:

```
void renderHealthBox(
  SDL_Renderer *renderer, int sideUiWidth, int yOffset, float percentage, float laksjdlkajsdlkasjdlkasjd) {
```

however I would want:

```
void renderHealthBox(
  SDL_Renderer *renderer, 
  int sideUiWidth, 
  int yOffset, 
  float percentage, 
  float laksjdlkajsdlkasjdlkasjd
) {
```

Is what I am looking for possible with clang-format?

My current config is:

```
Language: Cpp
IndentWidth: 2
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
ColumnLimit: 120
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
IndentCaseLabels: true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clang-format: force arguments and parameters to one-line-each if the statement overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626/clang-format-force-arguments-and-parameters-to-one-line-each-if-the-statement-o)

Comment: **TL;DR** of that one: `AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false`

Comment: @hlt the possible duplicate you marked does not fix my case as I am already using those settings but the `AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine` did fix the first example to be format like the second how I would still want the first / last arguments / parameters to be on there own line (like the final example I gave of what I am looking for).

Answer (score 5):

Is this configuration good enough? It's based on @hit's comment, but I don't think this question is a duplicate of the other one. The main part of it is `AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak`. From [clang-format documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> `BAS_AlwaysBreak` (in configuration: `AlwaysBreak`) Always break after an open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line

---

## Example:

`.clang-format`:

```
Language: Cpp
IndentWidth: 2
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
ColumnLimit: 120
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
IndentCaseLabels: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```

`test.cpp`:

```
void renderHealthBox(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int sideUiWidth, int yOffset, float percentage, float laksjdlkajsdlkasjdlkasjd) {
}

int main()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,153 + floor(toGreenRed * percentage),51 + floor(toGreenGreen * percentage),51 + floor(toGreenBlue * percentage),255);
}
```

`$ clang-format test.cpp`:

```
void renderHealthBox(
  SDL_Renderer *renderer,
  int sideUiWidth,
  int yOffset,
  float percentage,
  float laksjdlkajsdlkasjdlkasjd) {}

int main() {
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(
    renderer,
    153 + floor(toGreenRed * percentage),
    51 + floor(toGreenGreen * percentage),
    51 + floor(toGreenBlue * percentage),
    255);
}
```

The only difference from your desired format is that the closing parentheses are not on their own line. I think that's a bit of a strange requirement, so I don't think it's possible to achieve with `clang-format`.

Comment: the issue with the closing parentheses like that is that the arguments list of a function and any variables declared at the top of the function will look exactly the same without knowing where the argument list ends and the function begins without looking on the right to see where the `) {` is. I guess I will have to figure out a setting that I will be the easiest for me to ready without be able to do it this way.

Comment: You could use `BraceWrapping: AfterFunction: true`. This will put opening function braces on a separate line. Alternatively, you could set `ContinuationIndentWidth: 4`, so function parameters are indented more than the function body.

Comment: @ryanzec clang-format 14.0.0RC1 now supports `AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent` which will also give you the symmetry you want for the closing paren on the next line.

Comment: It's only a strange requirement because C++ unfortunately doesn't allow trailing commas in argument lists, even though they are allowed in initialiser lists. Apparently the "logic" is that initialiser lists are likely to be autogenerated but argument lists aren't. That's nonsense of course, and in languages where trailing commas are allowed in argument lists it's common to see this formatting style (e.g. Prettier does it like this for Javascript; it gives nicer results than clang-format).