# Force function arguments on individual lines

Tags: clang-format

I want to format arguments as one per line, e.g. as follows:

```cpp
cls.def(
    "isHomogeneousElastic",
    &SUB::System::isHomogeneousElastic,
    "isHomogeneousElastic");
```

However, clang-format wants to format this as:

```cpp
cls.def(
    "isHomogeneousElastic", &SUB::System::isHomogeneousElastic, "isHomogeneousElastic");
```

How can I avoid this?

---

I found [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626/clang-format-force-arguments-and-parameters-to-one-line-each-if-the-statement-o) with the solution of using:

```
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```

which works on some parts in my code, but not on this particular example.