# clang-format: how to put each input parameter in a line in function declaration and function definition?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Before posting this question, I researched here and saw some questions. The (nearly) same question is :
[force arguments and parameters to one-line-each if the statement overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626/clang-format-force-arguments-and-parameters-to-one-line-each-if-the-statement-o)

I have tried that solution with [clang-format online tool here](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/), it does not work (maybe it worked because the statement overflows). But my question is a little bit different:

Imagine I have a function `void myFunc(int a, int b, int c);`

I want to format it like this

myfile.h

```
void myFunc(
    int a,
    int b, 
    int c);
```

myfile.cpp

```
void myFunc(
    int a, 
    int b, 
    int c)
{
    // do something here
}
```

**I want always keep this format, no matter if the function length exceeds the column width or not.**
I have tried some solutions mentioned here in StackOverflow, but no solution works. How can I do it?