# Visual Studio: how to format each input parameter in a line in function declaration and function definition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-formatting

I have a function like this `void my func(int a, int b, int c);`
Is there any tool, any way or any VS extension to format (convert) my function as

```
void myfunc(
    int a,
    int b,
    int c);

void MyClass::myfunc(
    int a,
    int b, 
    int c)
{
     //do something
}
```

I have tried with clang-format editor and Artistic Style, but no work.

Answer (score 2):

After my test, I believe the following steps can achieve your needs, I suggest you refer to it:

1. Create a .clang-format file
   [image]
   2.Add the following code to the .clang-format file.

```
    AccessModifierOffset: 0
    AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: true
    AlignTrailingComments: false 
    AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
    AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
    AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true 
    AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false 
    AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false 
    BinPackParameters: false 
    BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false 
    ColumnLimit: 50 
    ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false 
    ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0 
    ContinuationIndentWidth: 0 
    AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
    Language: Cpp 
    IndentWidth: 4 
    TabWidth: 4 
    UseTab: Never
```

3.Select the function and press ctrl+k+d.

**Result:**

[image]

However, this format does not take effect when there are not many parameters, so it can only be used when the parameters meet a certain number.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, this question is the following question of another question of mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559539/clang-format-how-to-put-each-input-parameter-in-a-line-in-function-declaration , my requirement in that topic is, no matter how many input param a function has, we should always have this format. Therefore, I post the example in this topic with function having only 3 input params. Unfortunately, I can not find any solution on Internet for that until now. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.