# Make clang-format wrap all parameters if line wraps

Tags: clang-format

I've seen [clang-format: force arguments and parameters to one-line-each if the statement overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626) and that's not quite what I want. I did try playing with those settings BinPackArguments and BinPackParameters don't seem to be doing anything for me. I'm using clang-format through the vscode extension and I don't know how to check the command line it's using.

I currently have clang formatting code like this.

```cpp
function_with_lots_of_parameters("This is the first long string",
                                 "This is the second long string. It's even longer than the first one.",
                                 call_to_another_function(with_a_paremeter, or_two));
```

I want it to format like this

```cpp
function_with_lots_of_parameters(
  "This is the first long string",
  "This is the second long string. It's even longer than the first one.",
  call_to_another_function(with_a_paremeter, or_two));
```

I'm ok if the last closing paren and semicolon are on another line. I just want to not waste all of the indent space and wrap before the first parameter or argument in an if predicate.

My .clang-format is a slightly modified version of the Google standard.

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  Google
AccessModifierOffset: -1
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignArrayOfStructures: None
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   AlignAfterOperator
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind:            Always
  OverEmptyLines:  0
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakAfterAttributes: Never
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakArrays:     true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeInlineASMColon: OnlyMultiline
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     120
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks:   Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<ext/.*\.h>'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
IncludeIsMainRegex: '([-_](test|unittest))?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentRequiresClause: true
IndentWidth:     2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertBraces:    false
InsertNewlineAtEOF: false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
IntegerLiteralSeparator:
  Binary:          0
  BinaryMinDigits: 0
  Decimal:         0
  DecimalMinDigits: 0
  Hex:             0
  HexMinDigits:    0
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
LineEnding:      DeriveLF
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Never
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PackConstructorInitializers: NextLine
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
PPIndentWidth:   -1
QualifierAlignment: Leave
RawStringFormats:
  - Language:        Cpp
    Delimiters:
      - cc
      - CC
      - cpp
      - Cpp
      - CPP
      - 'c++'
      - 'C++'
    CanonicalDelimiter: ''
    BasedOnStyle:    google
  - Language:        TextProto
    Delimiters:
      - pb
      - PB
      - proto
      - PROTO
    EnclosingFunctions:
      - EqualsProto
      - EquivToProto
      - PARSE_PARTIAL_TEXT_PROTO
      - PARSE_TEST_PROTO
      - PARSE_TEXT_PROTO
      - ParseTextOrDie
      - ParseTextProtoOrDie
      - ParseTestProto
      - ParsePartialTestProto
    CanonicalDelimiter: pb
    BasedOnStyle:    google
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments:  true
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RemoveSemicolon: false
RequiresClausePosition: OwnLine
RequiresExpressionIndentation: OuterScope
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes:    CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: LexicographicNumeric
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterIfMacros:   true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  AfterRequiresInClause: false
  AfterRequiresInExpression: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles:  Never
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum:         1
  Maximum:         -1
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Auto
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - STRINGIZE
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force it on a case-by-case basis by manually adding a comment after the opening paren:

```cpp
function_with_lots_of_parameters( //
  "This is the first long string",
  "This is the second long string. It's even longer than the first one.",
  call_to_another_function(with_a_paremeter, or_two));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. clang-format only can place all arguments on a single line or a new single line, if they can fit a line, or each argument on own lines, or all arguments aligned after ( on several lines:

```
func(a, b, c);
func(
  a, b, c, d);
func(arg_a,
     arg_b,
     arg_c);
func(a, b, c,
     d, e);
```

Nobody seems to want to implement yet another arguments alignment rule in clang-format.