# ClangFormat: break and align if columnLimit is reached?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Here my `.clang-format` file:

```yaml
---
BasedOnStyle: Google
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignOperands: 'true'
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: 'false'
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: 'true'
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: 'true'
BinPackParameters: 'false'
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
ColumnLimit: '80'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: 'false'
Cpp11BracedListStyle: 'false'
IndentWidth: '4'
Language: Cpp
NamespaceIndentation: All
SortIncludes: 'true'
Standard: Cpp03

...
```

I have:

```
clang-format --version                   
Ubuntu clang-format version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
```

I am not happy with this format:

```
static inline VecABf clarke(Vec3f in) {
    float const sq3 = sqrtf(3.f);
    return VecABf(in.u - 0.5f * (in.v + in.w), sq3 * 0.5f * (in.v - in.w)) *
           (2.f / 3.f);
}
```

Since the expression is longer than 80 chars, I would like to be broken as follow:

```
static inline VecABf clarke(Vec3f in) {
    float const sq3 = sqrtf(3.f);
    return VecABf(
               in.u - 0.5f * (in.v + in.w), 
               sq3 * 0.5f * (in.v - in.w)
           ) * (2.f / 3.f);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483626/clang-format-force-arguments-and-parameters-to-one-line-each-if-the-statement-o

Comment: Also see https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#binpackarguments ... looks like you need binpackarguments false

Comment: @Den-Jason I saw this question, but the answer doesn't work :(